# How to drop columns which have same values in all rows via pandas or spark dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql, duplicates, multiple-columns

Suppose I've data similar to following:

```
  index id   name  value  value2  value3  data1  val5
    0  345  name1    1      99      23     3      66
    1   12  name2    1      99      23     2      66
    5    2  name6    1      99      23     7      66
```

How can we drop all those columns like (`value`, `value2`, `value3`) where all rows have the same values, in one command or couple of commands using **python**?

Consider we have many columns similar to `value`, `value2`, `value3`...`value200`.

Output:

```
   index    id  name   data1
       0   345  name1    3
       1    12  name2    2
       5     2  name6    7
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

What we can do is use `nunique` to calculate the number of unique values in each column of the dataframe, and drop the columns which only have a single unique value:

```
In [285]:
nunique = df.nunique()
cols_to_drop = nunique[nunique == 1].index
df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1)

Out[285]:
   index   id   name  data1
0      0  345  name1      3
1      1   12  name2      2
2      5    2  name6      7
```

Another way is to just `diff` the numeric columns, take `abs` values and `sums` them:

```
In [298]:
cols = df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns
diff = df[cols].diff().abs().sum()
df.drop(diff[diff== 0].index, axis=1)
​
Out[298]:
   index   id   name  data1
0      0  345  name1      3
1      1   12  name2      2
2      5    2  name6      7
```

Another approach is to use the property that the standard deviation will be zero for a column with the same value:

```
In [300]:
cols = df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns
std = df[cols].std()
cols_to_drop = std[std==0].index
df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1)

Out[300]:
   index   id   name  data1
0      0  345  name1      3
1      1   12  name2      2
2      5    2  name6      7
```

Actually the above can be done in a one-liner:

```
In [306]:
df.drop(df.std()[(df.std() == 0)].index, axis=1)

Out[306]:
   index   id   name  data1
0      0  345  name1      3
1      1   12  name2      2
2      5    2  name6      7
```

Comment: Caveat: dropping column by number of unique entries==1 ends up dropping columns that have only one non-NAN entry. That may or may not be the intent.

Comment: can someone help how to delete the columns that have 95% of same values

Answer (score 7):

A simple one liner(python):

```
df=df[[i for i in df if len(set(df[i]))>1]]
```

Comment: Great answer!
Alternative would be:
`df = df[[i for i in df if df[i].nunique()>1]]`

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column which are not compared and then compare first row selected by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with all `DataFrame` and last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['index','id','name',])
print (~df1.eq(df1.iloc[0]).all())
value     False
value2    False
value3    False
data1      True
val5      False
dtype: bool

print (df1.ix[:, (~df1.eq(df1.iloc[0]).all())].reset_index())
   index   id   name  data1
0      0  345  name1      3
1      1   12  name2      2
2      5    2  name6      7
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html), which returns the number of unique values in each column:

```
In [3]: df.loc[:, df.nunique() > 1]
Out[3]: 
   index   id   name  data1
0      0  345  name1      3
1      1   12  name2      2
2      5    2  name6      7
```

Answer (score 1):

pythonic solution

Original DataFrame

```
index id   name  value  value2  value3  data1  val5
    0  345  name1    1      99      23     3      66
    1   12  name2    1      99      23     2      66
    5    2  name6    1      99      23     7      66
```

Solution

```
for col in df.columns:  # Loop through columns
  if len(df[col].unique()) == 1:  # Find unique values in column along with their length and if len is == 1 then it contains same values
    df.drop([col], axis=1, inplace=True)  # Drop the column
```

Dataframe after executing above code

```
   index   id   name  data1
0      0  345  name1      3
1      1   12  name2      2
2      5    2  name6      7
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work also:

```
cols_to_drop  = []
for col in df:
    if df[col].std()==0:
        cols_to_drop.append(col)
df= df.drop(columns = cols_to_drop)
```