# spark Dataframe/RDD equivalent to pandas command given in description?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

How to perform same functionality as this pandas command via Pyspark dataframe or RDD ?

```
df.drop(df.std()[(df.std() == 0)].index, axis=1)
```

For details on what this command does, refer:
[How to drop columns which have same values in all rows via pandas or spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658574/how-to-drop-columns-which-have-same-values-in-all-rows-via-pandas-or-spark-dataf)

**Note**:

File is too big to use `df.toPandas()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can use `countDistinct`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct 

cnts = (df
    .select([countDistinct(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
    .first()
    .asDict())

df.select(*[k for (k, v) in cnts.items() if v > 1])

## +---+-----+-----+-----+
## | id|index| name|data1|
## +---+-----+-----+-----+
## |345|    0|name1|    3|
## | 12|    1|name2|    2|
## |  2|    5|name6|    7|
## +---+-----+-----+-----+
```

This won't work on data with cardinality but can handle non-numeric columns.

You can use the same approach to filter with standard deviations:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import stddev

stddevs = df.select(*[stddev(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).first().asDict()

df.select(*[k for (k, v) in stddevs.items() if v is None or v != 0.0])

## +---+-----+-----+-----+
## | id|index| name|data1|
## +---+-----+-----+-----+
## |345|    0|name1|    3|
## | 12|    1|name2|    2|
## |  2|    5|name6|    7|
## +---+-----+-----+-----+
```