# Remove columns with same values from a large csv file

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have a large csv file with thousands of columns (50,000 rows and 25,000 columns).
I want to;

1. Obtain the list of all columns with same values
2. Remove all column obtained in step 1

**Sample input**

```
F1,F2,F3,F4
0,2,1,4
0,1,1,3
0,3,1,3
0,2,1,3
```

**Sample output**

```
Columns with same values: F1 F2

F2,F4
2,4
1,3
3,3
2,3
```

I have implemented python based solutions which works fine for small files but are too slow for large files (more than 8 GB).

A solution in any programming language (but robust and fast) will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the solution you made in python.

Comment: A simple solution is available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658574/how-to-drop-columns-which-have-same-values-in-all-rows-via-pandas-or-spark-dataf

Comment: Then please delete this question or [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64945968/edit) your question to give information why that solution does not apply to your question.

Comment: @Luuk Its mentioned in the question, ".....but are too slow for large files (more than 8 GB). "

Comment: What is "too slow" it is a vague term, Some people consider 3 seconds to slow and other are happy with a solution that takes 10 minutes....

Comment: "too slow" in this case means that it is taking more than one hour for csv file to load , and afterwards kernel is automatically interrupted and restarts. I am using macOS Mjoave, 8 GB RAM, 1.3 GHz Intel Core i5. I hope it ''sufficiently'' explains "too slow". I tried to use Google Colab but it also times out.

Comment: Please don't post text as images.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Those images you posted are not CSVs. Maybe they're pictures of some tool rendering CSVs in some tabular fashion, idk. Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable **textual** sample input and expected output that are CSVs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another `awk`, using subset of @Luuk's sample input

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR && NR>1 {if(NR>2) for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i!=p[i]) c[i];
                            split($0,p); next} 
           FNR==1  {n=asorti(c,m); max=m[n]} 
                   {for(i in c) printf "%s",$i (i==max?RS:FS)}' file{,}
F2,F4
1,3
2,2
0,1
2,1
2,0
1,2
1,3
```

The trick is it's enough to check if any of the consecutive values are different.
some extra work to find the max included column index (required for clean printing).

If you have thousands of columns you can speed up the filtering by changing `i<=NF` to `i<=NF && !(i in c)`

Perhaps this alternative will be the fastest, which quickly removes the columns if there are different values from the search set.

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR && NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]; next} 
           NR==FNR {if(NR>2) for(i in a) if($i!=p[i]) {delete a[i]; c[i]};
                    split($0,p); next} 
           FNR==1  {n=asorti(c,m); max=m[n]} 
                   {for(i in c) printf "%s",$i (i==max?RS:FS)}' file{,}
```

All solutions double scans the file so it can't be very fast but I expect it to complete in couple minutes.  Please post the timings if you can test.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved the problem. My file have 50K rows and 25K columns, your code produced the output in 49 minutes.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for asorti()

Comment: @Ahmad 49 minutes seems like a very long time. I ran my script on a file that had 50K rows of 25K columns using cygwin on my old laptop and it took 18 minutes, see the bottom of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64947967/1745001), and I wouldn't expect a big difference between the 2 awk scripts.

Comment: @EdMorton For me 49. minutes is still better than a Python solution that was taking one hour to read the file and then would crash due to memory issues. :)
Another issue might the nature of the data which in my case is float (up to two decimal points), so perhaps  this might be a factor as well.

Comment: Have you tried the script I posted to see if it's still in that 49 minute ballpark for your real data?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
            vals[inFldNr][$inFldNr]
        }
    }
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
        if ( length(vals[inFldNr]) > 1 ) {
            out2in[++numOutFlds] = inFldNr
        }
    }
}
{
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(out2in[outFldNr]), (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
F2,F4
2,4
1,3
3,3
2,3
```

---

EDIT: tested against a file that's 50,000 lines of 25,000 fields:

```
$ time awk -f tst.awk file.csv file.csv > out.csv

real    17m42.591s
user    17m29.421s
sys     0m3.858s
```

The above input file was created by running this script:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","; x=50000; y=25000; for (i=1;i<=x;i++) for (j=1;j<=y;j++) printf "%s%s", (i>1?substr(rand(),3,1):"F"j), (j<y?OFS:ORS)}' > file.csv

$ wc file.csv
     50000      50000 2500113283 file.csv

$ ls -lh file.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 MyLogin None 2.4G Nov 22 12:45 file.csv
```

Comment: I tested the speed of this on my Windows machine (under WSL), and this finished in 34 minutes.  (`time awk -f tst.awk random.txt random.txt >random-awk.txt`   (real    34m5.464s user    12m5.615s sys     1m28.534s))  Output is the same (ignoring line-endings)

Comment: And `gawk.exe` directly on windows, did take 8min40sec. So WSL seems to be a slowing factor 

Comment: Rather surprisingly the code does not work for me (time gawk -f test.awk input.csv input.csv > output.csv)  the output.csv is same as input.csv. However, the code of @karakfa is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @Ahmad then you copy/pasted the code incorrectly. As you can see in my answer, it does work. You still haven't provided sample input/output in your question that we could test against though so maybe your input doesn't even look the way we're guessing it does.

Comment: @EdMorton I am equally surprised, I copy paste your code in a file "Morton.awk" and executed the command "time gawk -f morton.awk input.csv input.csv > output.csv". The file "output.csv" is same as "input.csv". The file "input.csv" is exactly same as given in the **Sample Input** in the question.

Comment: Ah, I see you replaced the images you had with text. That's the problem then - your input has a header line whereas the sample input @Luuk had created and I borrowed doesn't. That header line being present means there's always more than 1 value in each column. I'll tweak my answer to handle that.

Comment: Done and tested against your now-provided sample input/output.

Comment: Your test file will create columns with different values, so output will be the same as input.  A quick fix is change to `(i>1?(!(j%5)?j:substr(rand(),3,1)):"F"j)`

Comment: @karakfa I was just going for worst case scenario in terms of how many fields would need to be output as the OPs timing numbers seemed really high. I'm hoping the OP will do some realistic testing against their real data.

Comment: Yes, i guess time is mostly spent on I/O.  In my solution it speeds up checking with reduced number of columns but probable negligible.

Comment: Mine would speed up with more duplication and fewer output columns too, like I say I just went for the worst case scenario in terms of how long it'll take to run to see if it'd be anything like in the ballpark of the OPs numbers (it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

I created a piece of code in .NET 5.0, which has following output:
(EDIT: oops, i noticed i have compiled it for .NET 3.1 )

```
WHICH COLUMNS HAVE UNIQUE VALUES
0: True
1: False
2: True
3: False
TIME AFTER CHECKING UNIQUE COLUMNS: 72,9047581 secs
TIME AFTER WRITING NON UNIQUE COLUMNS TO NEW FILE: 221,751107 secs
```

This is under 4 minutes. My PC (running Windows) might be quicker then yours, but the difference, compared to 1 hour, is to large...

And i created an 'input file with 4 columns as your sample, like this:

```
D:\Temp>type random.txt
0,1,1,3
0,2,1,2
0,0,1,1
0,2,1,1
0,2,1,0
0,1,1,2
0,1,1,3
0,0,1,3
0,2,1,4
0,3,1,1
....
```

My example file has 2756616192 bytes, or 344577024 lines.

The output looks like this:

```
D:\Temp>type randomNEW.txt
1,3
2,2
0,1
2,1
2,0
1,2
1,3
0,3
2,4
3,1
```

this file has 1722885120 bytes, and has also 344577024 lines.

The source looks like this (note: I am not very experienced in C#, just learning, so there might be things that can be improved!):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp59
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            bool[] a = new bool[4];
            int[] first = new int[4];
            int t = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++ ) { a[i] = true; }

            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"d:\temp\random.txt"))
            {
                string[] s = line.Split(",");
                int[] b = new int[4]{ Convert.ToInt32(s[0]), Convert.ToInt32(s[1]), Convert.ToInt32(s[2]), Convert.ToInt32(s[3]) };

                if (t==0)
                {
                    first = b;
                } 
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        if (a[i]) a[i] = b[i] == first[i];
                    }
                }
                t++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("WHICH COLUMNS HAVE UNIQUE VALUES");
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {a[i]}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"TIME AFTER CHECKING UNIQUE COLUMNS: { ((DateTime.Now-start).TotalSeconds)} secs");

            StreamWriter n =  new StreamWriter(@"D:\temp\randomNEW.txt");
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"d:\temp\random.txt"))
            {
                string[] s = line.Split(",");
                string output = "";
                for (int i=0; i<4; i++ )
                {
                    if (!a[i]) output += String.Format($"{s[i]},");
                }
                if (output.EndsWith(",")) output = output.Substring(0, output.Length - 1);
                output += "\r\n";
                n.Write(output.ToCharArray());
            }
            n.Close();
            Console.WriteLine($"TIME AFTER WRITING NON UNIQUE COLUMNS TO NEW FILE: { ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds)} secs");
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just did a test on a Mac-MINI (Late 2012; macOS Catalina 10.15.7; 2.3 Ghz; 16Gb RAM)

```
TIME AFTER CHECKING UNIQUE COLUMNS: 104.473532 secs
TIME AFTER WRITING NON UNIQUE COLUMNS TO NEW FILE: 300.272936 secs
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I will try to execute it.